# Rails 4 - validate model is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Appreciate if you help me. I have a rails project, where people can book tickets to an airplanes (not a real project, just trying to learn rails :) ).

I have two cfaffolded objects - 'seats' and 'flights', and customer can buy a seat from every flight page (seats loads as partials).

My /app/views/flights/show.html.erb looks like that:

```
<p>
  <strong>Departure:</strong>
  <%= @flight.departure %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Destination:</strong>
  <%= @flight.destination %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Baggage allowance:</strong>
  <%= @flight.baggage_allowance %>
</p>

<%= render partial: "new_seat", locals: {seat: Seat.new(flight_id: @flight.id)} %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_flight_path(@flight) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', flights_path %>
```

My new_seat partial /app/views/flights/_new_seat.html.erb :

```
<h1>New Seat</h1>

<%= form_for(seat) do |f| %>
  <% if seat.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(seat.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this seat from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% seat.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :flight_id %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :baggage %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :baggage %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If it is important - I made new_seat partial by myself through copying it from /app/views/seats/new.html.erb

And now I need to validate baggage amount to prevent my clients grab big bags. I wrote my /app/models/seat.rb this way:

```
class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :flight
    def validate
        if baggage > flight.baggage_allowance
          seat.errors.add(:base, message: "You have too much baggage")
        end
    end
end
```

But it is not working - there is no errors on site when clients enters big amounts in baggage field. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validate` method is already available(its a class method that ActiveRecord provides us to implement our custom validations). You can use that method which AR provides. something like the code below

```
validate :check_baggage_limit

def check_baggage_limit
  if baggage > self.flight.baggage_allowance
    self.errors.add(:base, "You have too much baggage")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom validations in two ways.
**First is Custom method** like below

```
class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flight

  validate :baggage_limit
  def baggage_limit
    if baggage > flight.baggage_allowance
      errors.add(:base, message: "You have too much baggage")
    end
  end
end
```

**Second is Custom Validators**

```
class BaggageValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(seat)
    if seat.baggage > seat.flight.baggage_allowance
      seat.errors.add(:base, message: "You have too much baggage")
    end
  end
end

class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  belongs_to :flight
  validates_with BaggageValidator
end
```

You must have misread the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Comment: thank you, i'm just learning and there is so much information around :)